# error creating FileOutputStream file using Stream API and Lambda expressions

Tags: eclipse, lambda, java-8, fileoutputstream

I am trying to create a file through the `FileOutputStream` stream, if I use the `for`-loop, it does it correctly:

```
public class EjemploFileOutputStream {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    OutputStream fOut = null;
    
    try {
        fOut = new FileOutputStream("primero.dat");
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            fOut.write(i);
        }           
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fOut != null)
            try {
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {                   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    
    

}
```

}

but using the Stream API and Lambda expressions, it gives me an error

this would be the code:

```
public class EjemploFileOutputStream {

static OutputStream fOut2 = null;


/**
 * @param args
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  
    List<Number> cantidades = Arrays.asList(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
    try {
        fOut2 = new FileOutputStream("primero3.dat");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {            
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    cantidades.stream().map(cantidad->cantidad.intValue()).forEach(cantidad -> {
        try {
            fOut2.write(cantidad);

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fOut2 != null)
                try {
                    fOut2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    });
}
```

}

the error trace in the console (Eclipse):

[image: the error trace in the console (Eclipse)]

the sequence in debugger mode: The first value of the list enters apparently OK , cantidad=10

[image: first value of the list enters apparently]

The next value in the list enters apparently OK, cantidad=20:

[image: next value in the list enters apparently OK]

but when processing it, it catches the error exception:

[image: it catches the error exception]

I am trying different options, but while I wanted to know could any of you know how to avoid this error

Comment: Please, don't post Exceptions as images, copy it and past as a text. See [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) Also, when you're highlighting everything, it turns out that you're highlighting nothing. Use the bold font judiciously.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have the finally block to close the `OutputStream` on the inside of the stream block, where it gets executed after each iteration. You need to move the finally to after the catch block instead, and it will work:

```
public class EjemploFileOutputStream {
    static OutputStream fOut2 = null;
    
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
        List<Number> cantidades = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        try {
            fOut2 = new FileOutputStream("primero3.dat");
            cantidades.stream().map(cantidad->cantidad.intValue()).forEach(cantidad -> {
                try {
                    fOut2.write(cantidad);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        
            });
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {            
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fOut2 != null)
                try {
                    fOut2.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can also clean up the code by using the `try-with` construct, which takes care of closing the stream automatically:

```
public class EjemploFileOutputStream {
    
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
        List<Number> cantidades = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        try (OutputStream fOut2 = new FileOutputStream("primero3.dat")){
            cantidades.stream().map(cantidad->cantidad.intValue()).forEach(cantidad -> {
                try {
                    fOut2.write(cantidad);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
        
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

One last thing. Using an `IntStream` instead of a `List` removes the need to call `stream()` or the `map()` call:

```
public class EjemploFileOutputStream {
    
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FileNotFoundException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
      
        IntStream cantidades = IntStream.of(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
        try (OutputStream fOut2 = new FileOutputStream("primero3.dat")){
            cantidades.forEach(cantidad -> {
                try {
                    fOut2.write(cantidad);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `.map(cantidad->cantidad.intValue())` is obsolete in every variant. And since `List` also has a `forEach` method, there’s no need for `stream()` either. The difference is, you can call `forEach` on a `List` multiple times whereas you can call it only once on the `IntStream`.